# Global filter correct way of registering

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-core

I have an async action filter (IAsyncActionFilter). I want it to work globally, in all methods. I can register it with

```
services.AddMvc(options =>
{
     options.Filters.Add(typeof(RequestFilter));
});
```

In Startup class

I want to register it like

```
services.RegisterRequestFilter();
```

I can do that with an extension method like

```
    public static void RegisterRequestFilter(this IServiceCollection services)
    {
        services.AddMvc(options =>
        {
            options.Filters.Add(typeof(RequestFilter));
        });
    }
```

and then in startup use it but I don't know if it is correct because there will be 2 occurrences of `services.AddMvc`: one without any parameters and second with options parameter.

Is that a correct way of doing it or is there better solution?

Comment: If you add your Extension-method, you don't need the other call any more.

Comment: i think this is the best way, at least i cant come up with a better one

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There won’t be a problem with having multiple `AddMvc()` calls. The services, `AddMvc` registers under the hood, are registered in a way that they won’t be registered multiple times, and even if that was the case, it’s generally not a problem.

You could of course simply name your extension method `AddMvcWithRequestFilter` and only call that one instead of calling `AddMvc()` separately. That way, you would only be calling it once. But again, that won’t make that much of a difference.

If you really want to avoid calling `AddMvc()` from within your extension method, you can also just configure the `MvcOptions` directly, like this:

```
public static void RegisterRequestFilter(this IServiceCollection services)
{
    services.Configure<MvcOptions>(options =>
    {
        options.Filters.Add(typeof(RequestFilter));
    });
}
```

At that point, you could also consider making this an extension method on `IMvcBuilder` instead:

```
public static IMvcBuilder AddRequestFilter(this IMvcBuilder builder)
{
    builder.Services.Configure<MvcOptions>(options =>
    {
        options.Filters.Add(typeof(RequestFilter));
    });
    return builder;
}
```

Then, you could call it like this in your `Startup`:

```
services.AddMvc()
    .AddRequestFilter();
```

That would probably be the “cleanest” approach here.